# How to change JRBaseSubreport expression with JasperReports API

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport, php-java-bridge

I'm using *JasperReports API* through *PHP/Java Bridge*. This means that the *PHP* side is on another machine than the *Java* side and the two side doesn't share the same filesystem.

To load a report, I must read the *.jasper* file in *PHP* and convert it to a *`java.io.InputStream`* instance and load it with *`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader::loadObject`* static method.

So everything works fine until my report have *subreports* referencing a file that the *Java* side doesn't have access. So my solution was to visit all *subreports* (using *`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRElementsVisitor`* class), evaluate *subreport* expression, load the report using the same method as the main report, but it in parameters of the main report.

And then, here is my problem, I don't know how to change the ***JRBaseSubreport*** expression to point to the newly added parameter.

So my question is, how to change ***JRBaseSubreport*** expression?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you mean or not, but you can actually change the definition in your JRXML for the subreports from using a `String` to using `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport`

For instance it will usually add the following parameter to your report when you add a subreport:

```
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\reports\\"]]
    </defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

And for the subreport element itself it will add something like:

```
<subreport>
  <reportElement uuid="64d21a88-9389-49f5-ba63-1f33aac5a39f" x="821" y="0" width="200" height="100"/>
  <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
  <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "report4_subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Instead you of passing int the `SUBREPORT_DIR` pass in the compiled `JasperReport` Object. So change your parameter to:

```
<parameter name="SUBREPORT" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport" isForPrompting="false"/>
```

and then the subreport element too:

```
<subreport>
  <reportElement uuid="64d21a88-9389-49f5-ba63-1f33aac5a39f" x="821" y="0" width="200" height="100"/>
  <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
  <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Then it is just a matter of knowing what subreports you need for particular report.

**NOTE:** This does have the unfortunate side effect of it not running in `iReport`, but I usually just swap the parameter from a `JasperReport` to `String` instance when testing in `iReport` to get around it.